# How to define a helper types to be path-independent in a Scala type class?

Tags: scala, typeclass, path-dependent-type

Let us have a type class which depending on the type defines some more types to work with:

```
trait Container[T] {
  type Elem

  def get(c: T, i: Int): Elem
  def set(c: String, i: Int, v: Elem): T
}

implicit object StringContainer extends Container[String] {
  type Elem = Char

  def get(c: String, i: Int) = c(i)
  def set(c: String, i: Int, v: Char) = c.patch(i, Seq(v), 1)
}

val ops = implicitly[Container[String]]


ops.set("ABC", 1, ops.get("ABC", 1)) // works

ops.set("ABC", 1, 'X') // type mismatch; found   : Char('X') required: ops.Elem
```

Because types are path dependent the compiler complains when trying to use this, the error is:

> type mismatch;
>
> found   : Char('X')
>
> required: ops.Elem

You and I know `ops.Elem` is `Char`. My current workaround is to use `Elem` as a type parameter instead:

```
trait Container[T, Elem] {
  def get(c: T, i: Int): Elem
  def set(c: String, i: Int, v: Elem): T
}

implicit object StringContainer extends Container[String, Char] {
  def get(c: String, i: Int) = c(i)
  def set(c: String, i: Int, v: Char) = c.patch(i, Seq(v), 1)
}
```

The drawback is to recall the type class when needed one needs to provide all type arguments:

```
val ops = implicitly[Container[String, Char]]
```

Is there some way to define types in type-class so that they can be used as path-independent?

Comment: You can use the **Aux** pattern, but still you would need to recover the type member as a type parameter in some point, specially when asking for it. Your supposition that you know that `Elem` is `Char` is wrong, you can not prove that.

Comment: Thanks. I think "Aux pattern" is what I am looking for - perhaps a full answer could be made about it?

Comment: As for "know that Elem is Char is wrong": my reasoning is: I know `ops` is `StringContainer`. `StringContainer.Elem` is `Char, therefore `ops.Elem` is `Char`. You seem to know what you are talking about, though, therefore I guess there is some hole in this reasoning. Can you point it to me?

Comment: You know that `ops` is `StringContainer` but code doesn't - when you requested `implicitly[Container[String, Char]]` `StringContainer` was upcasted and lost information about concrete type of `Container#Elem`. If there was `StringContainer.Elem` compier would know that `Elem` is `Char`.

Comment: That explains it - type of `ops` is not `StringContainer.type`, only `Container[String]`. In contrast `StringContainer.set("ABC", 1, 'X')` works, because then the compilers knows the concrete type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are requesting just

```
Container[String]
```

instead of

```
Container[String] { type Elem = Char }
```

Try with type refinement

```
object Container {
  implicit val strContainer: Container[String] { type Elem = Char } = new Container[String] {
    type Elem = Char

    def get(c: String, i: Int) = c(i)
    def set(c: String, i: Int, v: Char) = c.patch(i, Seq(v), 1)
  }
}

val ops = implicitly[Container[String] { type Elem = Char }]
ops.set("ABC", 1, 'X') // ok
```

which with Aux pattern becomes something like

```
object Container {
  type Aux[T,Elem0] = Container[T] { type Elem = Elem0 }

  implicit val strContainer: Aux[String, Char] = new Container[String] {
    type Elem = Char

    def get(c: String, i: Int) = c(i)
    def set(c: String, i: Int, v: Char) = c.patch(i, Seq(v), 1)
  }
}


val ops = implicitly[Container.Aux[String,Char]]
ops.set("ABC", 1, 'X') // ok
```